# data annonation regular expression to check digit between specify numbers

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3

How to write a regular expression which contain format like **00:00**

the **00 before :** must be digit between 0-24 and **00 after :** must be digit between 0-59

i have my code below but somehow some it cannot work properly.

```
[RegularExpression(@"[0-24]+:[0-59]", ErrorMessage = "Format was invalid")]
```

For Exmaple

00:59 was accepted

25:60 was not accepted

Comment: put some sample values to be accepted and values to be rejected, will make more sense...

Comment: read [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html) and try out [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html), it shall definitely help you

Comment: +1 good question..but you need to understand the fact that using `REGEX` every now and then is not `COOL`..Its `sometimes` stupid thing to do!

Comment: I guess the question has totally changed as the correct answer is not an answer to the current question, whereas my answer is. Shame we can't both be marked as correct! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something simple like this?

```
[RegularExpression(@"(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])", ErrorMessage = "Format was invalid")]
```

It matches on any time from `00:00` to `23:59`. Note that it does not need the leading zero as written, so will also accept times like `7:00` or `7:3` for three minutes past seven (this is consistent with how you asked your question).

If you want it to require the leading zeros, just remove the question marks...

Comment: @Trouble this regex is incorrect!it even matches 344:523,300:200..Check out my solution answered below

Comment: @Anirudha: No it doesn't! My regex is correct. Try it using an online tool. e.g. http://regexpal.com/ It does NOT match 344:253, 300:200. Why did you downvote me?!

Comment: @Dommer I tested in `LINQPAD` with `C#` and it matched `200:300` as 00:30..sorry for down voting though!

Comment: @Anirudha: That's because it searched the entire string for a match and found `00:30` within the longer string. That's how regular expressions work. It works correctly as the MVC validation as that requires the entire string to be a match!

Comment: @Dommer my bad..can u edit so i can upvote it!

Comment: @Anirudha: That's very decent of you, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this `"([0-9]{1,2}|100):(1?[0-9]{1,2}|200)"`

Comment: i had tried but unfortunately it cannot work for me. Any input i key in seems wrong

Answer (score 1):

try with this: `\b(?:2[0-4]|1?\d):(?:5\d|[1-4]?\d)\b`

with leading zero:
`\b(?:2[0-4]|1\d|0?\d):(?:5\d|[1-4]\d|0?\d)\b`

Comment: Thanks!! It seems like can work properly for me. Can you help me with the above example i had edited again? Just wanna understand more. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to solve every problem by `REGEX`.You should not complicate things.Break down the code.This would make your code more readable and fluent.

The method below yields the perfect matches.

```
 public IEnumerable<string> getValues(string s)//this method returns the valid matches from s
    {
        Regex r=new Regex(@"\d{1,}:\d{1,}");
        foreach(Match m in r.Matches(s))
        {
        string[] str=m.Value.Split(':');

        if((int.Parse(str[0])>=0 && int.Parse(str[0])<=24) && (int.Parse(str[1])>=0&&int.Parse(str[1])<=59))
        yield return str[0]+":"+str[1];
        }
    }
```

Use the above method by using a for-each statement!

```
foreach(string s in getValues("5:16 100:200"))//getValues method yields the perfect match
Console.WriteLine(s);//5:16
```